# Syntax highlighting for R language

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting for R is not currently supported on Stack Exchange (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)). Currently, questions tagged [r](/questions/tagged/r) are using the "default" syntax highlighting (see in the code source of any page tagged with [r](/questions/tagged/r) the snippet `<div style="display:none" id="prettify-lang">default</div>`).

However R is supported by Google-code-prettify as an [extension](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-r.js). As the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag just passed the 50,000-questions milestone on Stack Overflow (with an additional 5,000 on Cross Validated), would it be possible to have our syntax highlighting implemented and linked to the tag?

**Edit: four months later**
The [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) is now close to 60,000 questions, on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) more than 6,000 questions, a couple hundreds answers on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), 40 questions on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) and 9 out of the 84 questions present on the brand new [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) beta are tagged with [r](/questions/tagged/r).

Comment: @Roland yes and for [codegolf.SE] and [codereview.SE] you're right, I'll change SO to SE.

Comment: It is, after all, a pirate's favorite programming language.

Comment: @Adam obligatory Paul and Storm: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqvA5IyfSSQ&feature=kp (edit: slightly NSFW, depending on where you work).

Comment: Now applied to stackoverflow, code golf, cross validated, data science, code review and programmers

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have now dragged in the lang-r stuff and set it against the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag; there may be some small delay while the cache expires etc, but you should be able to explicitly specify it via:

```
<!-- language: lang-r -->
```

Once the cache has cleared (i.e. when it picks it up implicitly from [r](/questions/tagged/r)) you should also be able to specify it (when there is ambiguity) via:

```
<!-- language: r -->
```

Comment: Brilliant news! Thanks!